# Why doesn't the watch window in sharpdevelop show the value of this variable?

Tags: c#, automation, outlook, sharpdevelop, outlook-redemption

Firstly let me say this code is developed in [SharpDevelop 4.3](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/), the code runs ok and gives the results it is supposed to, however the getting to that point was a little more difficult in terms of debugging because the watch window doesn't seem to present the values as I expected.
Can anybody tell me whether there is anything I should do to inspect the values in this loop?

The value of `mailItem.Subject` for instance is shown in the watch as: Object is not of type `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem` (I am a bit confused about the underscore as I read it is simply a naming convention and I believe I have removed the underscores throughout the project for my own preference) But I note that mailItem in the watch is showing as `System.__ComObject` - is this a clue that is lost on me?

```
//LOOPING THROUGH MAIL ITEMS IN THAT FOLDER.
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem in fldMailItems.Items)
{
    if (mailItem.Body != "")
    {
        MyMail mail = new MyMail();
    mail.Subject = (mailItem.Subject == null) ? string.Empty : mailItem.Subject;
    //mail.
    mailItems.Add(mail);
    }
}
```

To further illustrate the issue as it is applying with [Redemption RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm), the message box displays as you would expect but the watch window does not show that the property SenderName even exists - it shows base Class as value: object, within which `_Identity` and `Identity` both null, and a further Non-Public members with `m_ObjjectToDataMap` which also has a value of null.
Here is an example then causing the same headache:

```
    void ConnectOutlook()
    {
         session = new Redemption.RDOSession();
            session.Logon();
            inbox = session.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);          
    }

    void DisconnectOutlook()
    {
        session.Logoff();
        session = null;
    }


    void MainFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            ConnectOutlook();

            int i=0;
            foreach ( RDOMail mailItem in inbox.Items.Restrict("[MessageClass] = 'IPM.Note'"))
            {
                i++;
                MessageBox.Show(mailItem.SenderName);
            }

            ....
```

Comment: This same problem occurs using redemption RDOMail is also showing incorrectly in the watch window. If for instance I put mailItem.To as a watch item it shows Object is not of Type Redemption.IRDOMail
But this is not correct as this makes clear: MessageBox.Show(mailItem.To);

Answer (score 0):

Does the happen for all items in the folder or just some? You need to make sure you really have a regular message, bot a report item.

This does not apply to Redemption since in Redemption all message items (RDOReportItem, RDOMeetingIrtem, etc.) are derived from RDOMail.

Comment: I cannot see any properties of all mailItem whether it is an Outlook mailitem or Redemption RDOMail - it is every item irrespective of which folder.

Comment: If this happens for all COM objects, you really need to contact the SharpDevelop vendor...